# How to clear session after aspx page is closed?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I've an aspx page which is opened by javascript code as a popup page. When this page is opened, I do some stuff and put some datas into session such as Session["x"] = data. When I close the page, I want to set Session["x"] as null. How can I do ? At which event? Or at javascript side ?

Answer (score 2):

Add a custom page to clear session. Use `onunload` event of your popup page to call it.

```
<body onunload="HandleOnClose()">

function HandleOnClose()
{
        //the url of your session clearing page
        location.replace('/sessionclearpage.aspx') ;
}
```

Inside sessionclearpage.aspx clear your session.